# How are environmental variables safer than secrets.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, security, secret-key

In rails, the secrets.yml file has a default comment stating that you shouldn't keep production secrets in the repository, and instead they should read the values from the environment.  I have also read pretty much everywhere to keep you secret keys for various APIs in environment file to keep them safe.

My question is, how is this safer?  If you have a public repo, can't someone just look in your production.rb file to get your secret keys instead of looking in secrets.yml?  I don't understand how putting them in a different file in the same repo is safer.

Lastly, if you don't put your environment files in your repo, how does your server get these files if you are building them from your github repo?

I realize that I'm probably missing something in this process so any advice on helping me to understand the process would be appreicated.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that putting them in secrets.yml vs production.rb makes zero difference.  Putting them in any file that is checked into source control is the "no no" you are reading about.

As to how you get them onto the server, it depends on your setup.  I myself use Ansible to manage my servers and the environment variables are deployed as part of that.  You don't have to do that, you just need some way to have that file available on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) and the poorly-named "environment files".

The YAML file you're referring to does not say to read secrets from "environment files", but from the environment, by which they mean environment variables:

```
# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
```

Secrets are safe(r) in the enviroment because:

1. you won't accidentally check them into source control, because you can't
2. you won't accidentally screw up file permissions, because there's no files
3. O/S env vars can only be read by their user or root

You should clear your secret envvars before passing your environment to any child processes.